# How to randomnly shuffle the column data for each row and get the new index in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I have data with % columns id, alt1, alt2, alt3, price. I want to keep the price value in one of alt1, alt2,alt3 columns or sometimes keep at price column only and get the location.

Before: 
[image]

After: 
[image]

please suggest some efficient ways to keep  the price at different locations and get location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this in a vectorized way in base R :

```
set.seed(2017)
#Get columns to extract value from 
df$y <- sample(ncol(df[-1]), nrow(df), replace = TRUE)
#Create a row/column matrix
mat <- cbind(1:nrow(df), df$y + 1)
#Get the values from particular position
vals <- df[mat]
#Change values at the position
df[mat] <- df$price
#Change values in price. 
df$price <- vals
df

#  ID price Alt1 Alt2 Alt3 y
#1  A     1  1.0    3  3.4 4
#2  A   4.5  2.0    5  3.0 1
#3  B     1  5.6    4  5.0 2
#4  B     7  3.0    6  3.2 4
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B'), 
                 price = c(3.4, 4.5, 5.6, 3.2),
                 Alt1 = c(1, 2, 1, 3), 
                 Alt2 = c(3, 5, 4, 6), 
                 Alt3 = c(1, 3, 5, 7))
```

Comment: for the first row y=4 so price and Alt3 should get exchanged. but here just price value is assigned in Alt3

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part. Updated the answer.